# Decrypt PDF in Windows phone app

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8, itext

I need to decrypt a PDF file using the owner's password in a Windows phone app. The only library (which I've found) which gives me the possibility to do this is iTextSharp. So I've add it's package using nuget and everything compiled okay.

**Problem**

When I'm trying to do a decryption operation I get an exception because there is no ICloneable interface in Universal app's version of .NET. I've been looking into sources of iTextSharp which are available on [github](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) but it's quite complex to handle it and somehow replace using of this interface with something else.

**Question**

Is there any way to do such operation on Windows phone?

Comment: From the iText blog: http://itextpdf.com/blog/itextsharp-and-uwp. I expect that iText 7 will have UWP support.

Answer (score 1):

I personally really like iTextSharp, however have not had to deal with that particular issue or decrypting passworded documents.

If you're flexible there, check this out https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf

Comment: It's not exactly what I've been looking for because it's not free but it do it's job so thanks.